# ExtJS 4.2 Change Group by this column

Tags: c#-4.0, extjs4.2

By default my ExtJS 4.2 Grid is grouping correctly.I want to know the event that is called when we click Group By This Field in ExtJS 4.2.I want to get the column value on this grouping has to be done and save the column field in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but let's give it a shot.

The following event is fired when changing the grouping of a grid.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-groupchange

```
store.on('groupchange', function (store, groupers) {
    // group values available here
    var values = store.groups.keys;
    // name of the column currently grouped by
    var columnField = groupers.keys[0];
    // then do whatever you want with these values
});
```